# How to check if a line of a txt file is empty in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, html-table, nightwatch.js

I have the following code it should compare the values of a csv file with the values in the browser. The Values in the browser are stored in a Table.

```
var testarray = [];
      var text = fs.readFileSync('..\...\fileName.csv');
      rd.on('line',function(line) {
          var x = 1;
      })
      .on('close', function(line) {
          close csv
      });

      if (x = 1 ){
          rd.on('line',function(line) {
          var x = 1;
      })
      .on('close', function(line) {
        close csv
      });
      }

      var i;
      while (i <|= testarray.length) {
       browser.expect.element('Column name of value').which.contains.text('index of the current array') 
       i + 1;
      }
```

Comment: So what is your problem specifically? You have blank lines in your CSV too that you want to ignore? I don't know nightwatch but you don't appear to be doing anything with the CSV lines as you read them.

Comment: no it just have to run til the end and the last line is empty